# Empty results on cloudkit text search

Tags: xcode, cloudkit

I have a number of records in my cloudKit public database and I would like to return those with text matching a given 'searchTerm' text string.

If I use this predicate I get all of the records (up to the maximum limit)

```
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(value: true) // returns records
```

When I try to just return records containing a partial search term I get nothing

```
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", searchTerm) // - empty
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains %@", "H")// empty
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "allTokens TOKENMATCHES[cdl] %@", searchTerm) // empty
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains 'H'")// empty
```

But when I search for a complete word the search works

```
let myPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "self contains 'Honda'") // returns matching records
```

Is there a way to do a partial search eg wild cards or similar?

This is a repeat of a qaestion I asked 5 years ago(!)

Comment: Looks like nothing has changed in this regard since you originally asked it!

Comment: Indeed! Seems like a pretty basic requirement. I'm moving over to a php/mysql web service solution

Comment: FYI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquery#1666032. No TOKENMATCHES in the Table 2. "self contains %@" works fine, it's a tokenized search based on word, not some characters only. so You can use "self contains 'NYU'" instead of "self contains U" to match "a student of NYU".